# Spring Cloud Spring Service Connector with RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-connectors

I use Spring cloud Spring service connector to connect Rabbitmq service on CloudFoundry.

```
public class CloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitFactory()
    {
         return connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

But I need to declare a CachingConnectionFactory and set its PublisherConfirms true. Because we need use publisherConfirm to check ack when we send message to queue. I have no idea about how to inject the connectionFactory which is got from cloud spring service connector. Or how we could handle this situation.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_rabbitmq) includes examples of customizing details of the connection provided by Connectors.

In your case, you should be able to do something like this:

```
@Bean
public RabbitConnectionFactory rabbitFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("publisherConfirms", true);

    RabbitConnectionFactoryConfig rabbitConfig = new RabbitConnectionFactoryConfig(properties);
    return connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory(rabbitConfig);
}
```

Comment: Cool - I did not know that. Note there's a [typo in the documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/issues/220). The actual return type is `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for the issue Gary, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: @ScottFrederick I have another issue want to ask you. I implement our project as you said. But it throw an exception that properties publisherConfirms couldn't write.There is no setter. I use 1.6.9v amqp lib. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: @Maxwell does the exception show the class that it is trying to set `publisherConfirms` on? I was assuming it would be set on `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory`, which does have a setter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html.

Comment: @ScottFrederick but the Connection get from connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory() is org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory(interface) in spring cloud config, not org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnection‌​Factory. Did we need to cast it to this type and set publisherConfirms?

Comment: This is the exception :[org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'publisherConfirms' of bean class [com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory]: Bean property 'publisherConfirms' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?"

Answer (score 0):

You can reconfigure the CCF created by the connector as follows:

```
@Bean
public SmartInitializingSingleton factoryConfigurer() {
    return new SmartInitializingSingleton() {

        @Autowired
        private CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

        @Override
        public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
            this.connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
        }
    };
}
```

You must be sure not to perform any RabbitMQ operations before the application context is fully initialized (which is best practice anyway).

Comment: Will @RabbitListener influence the settings ?

Comment: You means I could configure it like this? And I also need to configure @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitFactory()
    {
         return connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory();
    }

Comment: Scott's solution is better.

Comment: Today, I try the snippet code in my project. But I found it didn't work until now. However ack true or false.

Answer (score 0):

This is RabbitTemplate

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setMandatory(true);
    template.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    template.setConfirmCallback((correlationData, ack, cause) -> {
        if (!ack) {
            System.out.println("send message failed: " + cause + correlationData.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Publisher Confirm" + correlationData.toString());
        }
    });
    return template;
}
```

This is spring-cloud config:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("publisherConfirms", true);
    RabbitConnectionFactoryConfig rabbitConfig = new RabbitConnectionFactoryConfig(properties);
    return connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory(rabbitConfig);
}
```

When I use this sender to send message.The result is not expected.

```
@Component
public class TestSender {

@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * *  * * ? ")
public void send() {
System.out.println("===============================================================");
    this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(EXCHANGE, "routingkey", "hello world",
            (Message m) -> {
                m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("tenant", "aaaaa");
                return m;
            }, new CorrelationData(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println("Sender Msg Successfully - " + date);
}
```

}